# Load image from local URL file with path

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

In my application, I am writing an image to a URL file and saving the relative URL in order to retrieve the image later on. This is what I am doing, but it is not working. Is there anything you see wrong.

```
let imageRelativeURL = pendingPostData[2]
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let urlString = "\(documentsPath)/\(imageRelativeURL).jpg"
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: urlString)
// This is the line that is causing the error
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)
```

I am getting this error:

> Thread 1: FATAL ERROR: Unexpectedly found nil while wrapping an Optional Value

This is how I am saving the relative URL.

```
let uniqueRelativeID = NSUUID().uuidString
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/\(uniqueRelativeID).jpg"
let relativePath = "\(uniqueRelativeID).jpg"
let relativeURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: relativePath)
let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath, relativeTo: relativeURL)

do {
    try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImg, 1.0)?.write(to: imageURL)
} catch {
    print("There was a problem writing image file.")
}

saveVideoData(data: imageURL.relativeString)
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Check `ChosenImg` should not be empty

Comment: I just added the line causing the error, forgot to put that in there. @rmaddy. It's because I am trying to get the data of the image

Comment: Look at the value for imageRelativeURL and the problem will be obvious.